# Can't do PHP curl or getimagesize()

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, php-curl, getimagesize

I'm debugging a sudden issue on a client site where we need to get the dimensions of some images. The getimagesize() is not working anymore, it just spins and spins forever. Not sure what the issue is. I see ALLOW_URL_FOPEN is on in php.ini so that shouldn't be the issue.

I try switching to cURL to get the size that way. Like so:

```
$headers = array(
    "Range: bytes=0-32768"
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$raw = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$img = imagecreatefromstring($raw);

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

return array(1,1);
```

And here cURL is doing the same thing, forever loading a white screen with no indication of what error it is. Even with the timeout. Also function_exists('curl_init') is true as is extension_loaded('curl').

What could be wrong? It's probably server related but I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: Are you sure the host is reachable from the server? (I'm assuming in your script $url has a value)

Comment: @jcorry yes we are just using URLs from images on the current site. not external.

Comment: Weird, why get them from HTTP then? Wouldn't it be faster/easier to just get them with the local filesystem?

Comment: @bishop sorry Cmd + Z too many times. that was the wrong ver of code. See edited code.

Comment: @jcorry I'm not sure what you mean by from the filesystem. how is that different than getimagesize()

Comment: You can also use [FastImage](https://github.com/tommoor/fastimage) that was created solely for this purpose.

Comment: @pinksharpii He means use `file_get_contents()` instead of `curl` and use `/local/path/to/file` instead of `http://example.com/path/to/file`

Comment: ^ yes, exactly. getimagesize() will take a local file path OR a url.

Comment: @AdamCopley See this is what I'm trying to say that it's a server issue, not a programatic issue. file_get_contents() also gives me spinning wheel forever. getimagesize() worked before so it shouldn't be an issue with my programming. I just don't know where to look next in terms of server settings. All these functions should work. Even cURL would spit out an error if it couldn't reach the URL. but it's not even doing that. It's just spinning forever.

Comment: Try `curl -v $url` from the command line where `$url` is the exact URL it is failing on in the PHP.  It may be trying to use ipv6, or suddenly the server can't resolve it's own IP/hostname, or it's trying to go over the public interface rather than locally so firewall or NAT are interfering.